# How to change the webpack config for styled components if there is already another instance of styled components in the same page?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, styled-components

I'm working on a React UI module, which uses styled components, for a part of the page where there is already another module that uses styled components. Because there is this pre-existing instance of styled components on that page, it conflicts with my code and does not display any css applied using this lib.

There's an FAQ for it which gives a solution, but by trying it I'm getting some other issue related to webpack as below.

This is the [FAQ link](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/faqs#running-multiple-applications-on-one-page) that I referred.

And I changed my config accordingly like so:

```
entry: {vendor: ['styled-components'], app: './src/index.js'},
externals: {
  'styled-components': {
    commonjs: 'styled-components',
    commonjs2: 'styled-components',
    amd: 'styled-components',
    root: 'styled'
  }
},
plugins: [
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: "vendor",
    minChunks: Infinity,
  })
]
```

Also, the `filename` in the `output` config is changed to:
`filename: '[name].js'`

My webpack version is `3.10.0`.

This config is resulting in the error `webpackjsonp is not defined`.

Maybe the approach to the original problem as per the FAQ is correct and applicable to my case, but I could be missing something in the config. Please help!

Comment: so you have two applications on one page?

Comment: Basically the whole page is divided into smaller UI modules, and each one is developed by different teams.

Comment: why are you using externals and commonChunksPlugin . doesn't one not bundle the dependency, while the other bundles it to a separate chunk?  aren't those contradictory?

Comment: Makes sense, but I doubt whether that will help the problem as ultimately the page will end up with two instances of styled components. I had given up on this lib for this reason and instead switched to react-emotion. It worked like a charm, and with just minor code changes for css.

Answer (score 3):

i got it working with this configuration

```
externals: {
    'styled-components': 'styled-components'
},
```

but in the main app i had to make styled-components as global variable and manually add some styled-components functions to it to make it working.

```
import styled, { 
   keyframes, css, createGlobalStyle, ThemeProvider 
} from 'styled-components';

window['styled-components'] = styled;
window['styled-components'].keyframes = keyframes;
window['styled-components'].css = css;
window['styled-components'].createGlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle;
window['styled-components'].ThemeProvider = ThemeProvider;
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'm trying to find a solution to this problem. I haven't yet, but the OP's approach won't work (and hasn't worked for me, and this is why.

First, the externals option in that configuration will skip bundling styled-components, however it will then try to find the dependency from the sources listed in the options. I have yet to have it successfully find the library that way, so this option doesn't work.

Second, the CommonsChunkPlugin wraps the app.js (or whatever your main file is called) in a webpackJsonp() function, designed to load the content properly with its dependencies from the vendor file. Because of this, the vendor file must be loaded prior to your app.js file, because it sets up the webpackJson() function.

This is a deeply frustrating topic. I'm trying to build a UI using micro-frontends, some of which use styled-components, and the restriction on only allowing a single library is driving me nuts. This is a horrible design decision and I have nothing but contempt for the library creators for forcing it upon us.

Comment: Maybe you should move to emotion/react-emotion then, it offers similar capability as styled-components and is even better. I mentioned that in my last comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had posted a solution as a comment to my question, but I guess sometimes that's not easily noticeable to someone else. Hence, pasting my comment here as an answer.

I had given up on this lib for this reason and instead switched to [react-emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction). It worked like a charm, and with just minor code changes for css.